# Input/output file.txt in bash shell

Tags: bash

I don't know how to read input array number in `input.txt` and write result in `output.txt`.
Example:

```
input.txt have array 7 8 9 2 
write result sort in output.txt 2 7 8 9
```

How can I do it?

Comment: " input.txt have array 7 8 9 2" is no useful information. What is that to be, different lines? Data within the same line?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose input is in input.txt and you want output in output.txt. Make a python script and name it sort.py like this:

```
l=map(int,raw_input("").strip().split())
l.sort() 
print l  # It will store it as a list

# or more precisely your answer can be
k=""
for i in l:
    k+=str(i)+" "
print k       #same output as you want
```

Run it in the terminal :

```
python sort.py < input.txt > output.txt
```